# TikZ: Connect a horizontal path to the edge of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to convert a diagram from a PNG to TikZ in LaTeX. I want to have two arrows that are pointing to a circle to point horizontally and to point to the edge of the circle. I almost get that by using a `.west` coordinate, but it doesn't quite align:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 [engine/.style={circle,minimum size=6cm,draw=black,font=\large
  }, block/.style={
   rectangle,minimum size=10cm,draw=black,dashed,font=\large
  }, point/.style={
   circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,fill=none
  }
 ]

 % Draw the rectangle containing the block diagram
 \node (block) [block] at (0,0) {};
 % Put a label at the top of the box
 \node (blockname) [point] at (0, 4.5) {\large Module};

 % A circle representing the engine
 \node (engine) [engine] at (1,-1) {Engine};

 % Inputs representing the network ports
 \node (input1) [point] at (-6,-3) {};
 \path (input1) edge [->] node [below] {Network A} (input1-|engine.west);

 \node (input2) [point] at (-6,-0.5) {};
 \path (input2) edge [->] node [above] {Network B} (input2-|engine.west);

 % Output
 \node (output) [point] at (-6,3) {};
 \node (outputup) [point] at (1,3) {};
 \path (outputup) edge [->,dashed]
                  node [above] {Management}
                  node [below] {Output}
                  (output);
 \path (outputup) edge [->,dashed] (engine);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what I have:

[image: My attempt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may use "intersecting paths", which are discribed in the TikZ manual p34 and 35 (http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf).

**EDIT**

Sorry for my first comment, due to a lack of time...
This is a complete example with your code showing how to achieve that :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 [engine/.style={circle,minimum size=6cm,draw=black,font=\large
  }, block/.style={
   rectangle,minimum size=10cm,draw=black,dashed,font=\large
  }, point/.style={
   circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,fill=none
  }
 ]

 % Draw the rectangle containing the block diagram
 \node (block) [block] at (0,0) {};
 % Put a label at the top of the box
 \node (blockname) [point] at (0, 4.5) {\large Module};

 % A circle representing the engine
 \node (engine) [name path=engine, engine] at (1,-1) {Engine};

 % Inputs representing the network ports

 \node (input1) [point] at (-6,-3) {};
 \path [name path=refline] (-6,-3) -- (6,-3);
 \node (intersect) [name intersections={of=engine and refline, by=x}] at  (intersection-1) {};
 \path (input1) edge [->] node [below] {Network A} (input1-|intersect);


 \node (input2) [point] at (-6,-0.5) {};
 \path (input2) edge [->] node [above] {Network B} (input2-|engine.west);

 % Output
 \node (output) [point] at (-6,3) {};
 \node (outputup) [point] at (1,3) {};
 \path (outputup) edge [->,dashed]
                  node [above] {Management}
                  node [below] {Output}
                  (output);
 \path (outputup) edge [->,dashed] (engine);
```

To achieve it, I created a node representing the line you want to create, then another node representing the first intersection between the circle and the line and I ended by linking the line with this last node.
In order to do that, you also need to use the intersections library, loaded by : `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`.

Result :

[image]

I hope it may help.

Comment: Please elaborate, as link-only answers are discouraged, since links may rot over time.

Comment: Sorry for first comment, I edited it with a complete example.